# Custom Fonts are not Showing Properly With Only One Color Showing

Tags: java, android, fonts

I have been having some troubles with multicolored fonts lately. The font I have uses the colors white and black, but for some reason only black is showing, and the inner white is not showing. Did I do something wrong, or is there a way to get the font color in there? Thank You. Here is the code --

```java
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/editundo.otf");

//crating color fill and adding in font to the paint and setting the color fill white and text size 150
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(tf);
paint.setTextSize(150);

// do other setup on Paint object
// Draw all the text stuff
//if the screen has not been tapped touch screen to start
if (f == 0) {
    canvas.drawText("Tap to Start", MainActivity.screenWidth / 4, MainActivity.screenHeight / 2, paint);
}

//Setting text as 40 size and draw the score text
paint.setTextSize(40);
canvas.drawText("Score: " + score, 10, 50, paint);
canvas.drawText("High Score: " + HighScore, 10, 120, paint);
paint.setTextSize(35);
canvas.drawText("Car Tokens: " + coinz, MainActivity.screenWidth*7/9+MainActivity.screenWidth*2/100, 50, paint);
```

Also, the font I am using is Mouser Outline font, and I have used it as both .otf and .ttf. The link to the font is here -- http://fontzone.net/font-details/mouser-outline

Thanks Again for your help.

Comment: All you need to do is set the color on your paint object: `paint.setColor(Color.WHITE)`

Comment: I tried that. It did not work, and also I want the inner part white.

Answer (score 0):

Colorful Font wont work as java.awt. Font only supports a variety of certain text/settings like bold, size, italics etc...

The only way I know of to write a font to a screen is to save each character as an image....

As explained here:

[Java - Multi-colored text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874132/java-multi-colored-text)

With the limitations of font being shown here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html

Comment: Wait. Are you suggesting using bitmap fonts?

Comment: I get what you mean and thank, but, the link shown does not have an actual answer.

Comment: Its fine. I was just pointing in the direction on conversion. Implementation for android is probably going to be a little different